# Dropdown Select Distinct based on Text property in a List

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a requirement that I need to get a list of unique / distinct Items for my dropdown value. See the example below,

**Example Data**

```
Id                Text

1                 AAA
2                 BBB
3                 AAA
4                 CCC
5                 BBB
```

I want the result list should be,

```
Id                Text

1                 AAA
2                 BBB
4                 CCC
```

**I tried so far**

```
 var Value = (from x in db.Items
                     where ((x.CallNo.StartsWith(q) || x.CallNo.Contains(" " + q)) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.CallNo)))
                     select new
                     {
                         id = x.Id,
                         text = x.CallNo
                     }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Meaning, I want the list to distinct based on the Text property. And also, the very first occurrence.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show us your affords.

Comment: "Distinct by more than one property" sounds different to "distinct based on the Text property"

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `GroupBy` and `First`:

```
var Value = db.Items
    .Where(x => x.CallNo.StartsWith(q) || x.CallNo.Contains(" " + q)) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.CallNo))
    .GroupBy(x => x.CallNo)
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .Select(x => new
        {
            id = x.Id,
            text = x.CallNo
        })
    .ToList();
```

If you actually want to get distinct objects by multiple properties as your title suggests use an anonymous type in the `GroupBy`.

```
.GroupBy(x => new { x.CallNo, x.OtherProperty})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define groups on multiple properties, here's how:

```
List<something> myList= employee.GroupBy(p => new {p.employeeId, p.employeeName} )
  .Select(g => g.First())
  .ToList();
```

Comment: But he mentioned _"distinct based on the Text property"_

Answer (score 0):

`Distinct` has an overload that takes an `IEqualityComparer<TSource>`. So you can write a comparer and supply that.
Alternatively, you can write a `DistinctBy` (extension) method. You can find it in Jon Skeet's [MiscUtil library](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/miscutil/). But you can also easily write it yourself:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
{
    var found = new HashSet<TKey>(comparer);
    return source.Where(element => found.Add(keySelector(element)));
}
```

Edit: I actually meant the [MoreLinq library](https://github.com/morelinq), but MiscUtil is useful too.
And note this method is for `IEnumerable`, not `IQueryable`.